# How do i add a Table View inside a UICollection View Cell Using Swift?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, ios8, uicollectionview

How do i add a table view inside a UICollectionViewCell? I'm not sure really were to start. How do i get the table view datasource and delegate out? Here is what i have tried already...

I Tried Google Searching it, but all i get is how to add collection view in a table view, not the other way around.

```
 import UIKit

    class GeneralAisleViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

        @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!


        var tableView:UITableView = UITableView()

        var CollectionViewArray = ["1", "2", "3"]

var tableView1Array = ["1", "2"]
        var tableView2Array = ["1", "2"]
var tableView3Array = ["1", "2"]


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


            self.collectionView.delegate = self
            self.collectionView.dataSource = self

            self.tableView.delegate = self
            self.tableView.dataSource = self

        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }


        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return CollectionViewArray.count
        }


        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

            let cell:UICollectionViewCell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell


            let dataToDisplay:String = CollectionViewArray[indexPath.row]

            let dataLabel:UILabel = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel




            dataLabel.text = dataToDisplay


            let TableView = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UITableView

            self.tableView = TableView




            return cell
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding a`UITableView` in a`UICollectionView`(Cell) is no difference vice versa.

You just need to be clear who is the`UITableView's` delegate and dataSource. From your code, it's`GeneralAisleViewController` to be.

Then what you need to do is to add`UITableView` into the cell's sub views, like:

**Code:**

```
...
let TableView = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UITableView
self.tableView = TableView
cell.addSubview(TableView)
return cell
```

Then the table view will fetch the table view cells from its dataSource.

However, things are never easier than they look like.
`UITableView` and`UICollectionView` both share the `reuse` technique for their cells, so every time you got a cell from the queue, they are reused, not created, so you need to be extremely careful to handle them after you got a cell.

Better to use `prepareReuse` to clean up the cell's sub views before you assign other properties or views into the cell.